# В чем разница между ABC и ABCMeta?

Tags: python

Хотелось бы прояснить отличия между `ABC` и `ABCMeta` из модуля `abc`.
Не совсем понимаю разницу в практическом применении. В [документации](http://grep.cs.msu.ru/python3.8_RU/digitology.tech/docs/python_3/library/abc.html) сказано, что `ABC` - это

> Вспомогательный класс, который использует ABCMeta в качестве своего метакласса.

При этом:

> Следует отметить, что тип ABC все еще является ABCMeta, поэтому
> наследование от ABC требует обычных мер предосторожности в отн.....и т.д.

Я, честно говоря, так и не понял их отличия, кроме того, что класс, созданный через `ABCMeta` пропадает из MRO:

```
class Parent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self):
        pass 


class Child(Parent): 
    def f(self):
        pass


print(Child.mro()) # [<class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class 'abc.ABC'>, <class 'object'>]

class Parent(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self):
        pass 


class Child(Parent): 
    def f(self):
        pass


print(Child.mro())  # [<class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, !нет abc! <class 'object'>]
```

Подскажите, когда какой использовать и есть ли особая разница?

Comment: Поздно, но нашёл похожий вопрос. Не могу закрыть этот, т.к. тот вопрос не на ru-сегменте.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335005/is-there-any-difference-between-using-abc-vs-abcmeta